# Building a Chrome searchbar replica

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a small searchbar. The searchbar works really fine but when jumping to a result, the scrolling is wrong. The first result is on top, but the searchbar still scrolls down. There is no need for scrolling down.

The chrome searchbar just scrolls when needed. The result is always in the center on screen I think.

So this is my current searchbar

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  defaultText = $("#loremIpsum").html(); // store an empty text as default

    $('#searchBar').on('input',function() { // search when receiving new input
        search();
    });
});

var defaultText = null;
var results = null; // the found results
var currentResultIndex; // the current focused result

function search() { // start searching
    var keyword = $("#searchBar").val(), // the text the user is looking for
        textSource = defaultText; // reset the result

    currentResultIndex = 0; // start with the first result

    keyword = keyword.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");

    var pattern = new RegExp("(" + keyword + ")", "gi");

    textSource = textSource.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    textSource = textSource.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

    $("#loremIpsum").html(textSource); // paste the new text with the marked results

    results = $("mark"); // store all results

    if (results.length > 0) {
        currentResultIndex = 1;
        setResultText(); // write down "result number 1 of 150 .."
        focusResult(); // scroll to the current result
    }
}

function goToNextResult() { // scroll to the next result
    if (results.length > 0) {
        currentResultIndex++;

        if (currentResultIndex > results.length) { // when reaching the max index, go back to the first
            currentResultIndex = 1;
        }

        setResultText();
        focusResult();
    }
}

function goToPreviousResult() { // scroll to the previous result
    if (results.length > 0) {
        currentResultIndex--;

        if (currentResultIndex == 0) { // when reaching the min index, go back to the last
            currentResultIndex = results.length;
        }

        setResultText();
        focusResult();
    }
}

function setResultText() {
    $("#resultCounter").html(currentResultIndex + " of " + results.length); // a counter of results
}

function clearSearch() { // clear the search bars text
    $("#searchBar").val("");
    search();
    $("#resultCounter").html("&nbsp;");
}

function focusResult() { // scroll to the current result and mark it
    var targetElement = results[currentResultIndex - 1];
    $("mark").removeClass("hasFocus");
    $(targetElement).addClass("hasFocus");  
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetElement).offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
#loremIpsum{
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.resultBtn{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: -90px;
}

#resultCounter{
    text-align: center;
}

.hasFocus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainContent">
            <input id="searchBar" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button onclick="goToNextResult()">Next</button>
            <button onclick="goToPreviousResult()">Previous</button>
            <button onclick="clearSearch()">Clear</button>
            <p id="resultCounter">&nbsp;</p>

            <p id="loremIpsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
```

When jumping to a result, the mainContent scrolls down/up.

The problem is, the page gets scrolled even on the first result on top for example. And the result is not focused, a wrong height is calculated.

The target is not calculated correctly.

[image: Scroll]

So how can I make the bar scroll just on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it already. I just modified the `focusResult()` function to subtract the `window height / 2` from your `scrollTop()` value. Now every result that gets focused aligns itself in the **middle of the window**. Is this what you want?

**Here you go with a working fiddle:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  defaultText = $("#loremIpsum").html(); // store an empty text as default

    $('#searchBar').on('input',function() { // search when receiving new input
        search();
    });
});

var defaultText = null;
var results = null; // the found results
var currentResultIndex; // the current focused result

function search() { // start searching
    var keyword = $("#searchBar").val(), // the text the user is looking for
        textSource = defaultText; // reset the result

    currentResultIndex = 0; // start with the first result

    keyword = keyword.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");

    var pattern = new RegExp("(" + keyword + ")", "gi");

    textSource = textSource.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    textSource = textSource.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

    $("#loremIpsum").html(textSource); // paste the new text with the marked results

    results = $("mark"); // store all results

    if (results.length > 0) {
        currentResultIndex = 1;
        setResultText(); // write down "result number 1 of 150 .."
        focusResult(); // scroll to the current result
    }
}

function goToNextResult() { // scroll to the next result
    if (results.length > 0) {
        currentResultIndex++;

        if (currentResultIndex > results.length) { // when reaching the max index, go back to the first
            currentResultIndex = 1;
        }

        setResultText();
        focusResult();
    }
}

function goToPreviousResult() { // scroll to the previous result
    if (results.length > 0) {
        currentResultIndex--;

        if (currentResultIndex == 0) { // when reaching the min index, go back to the last
            currentResultIndex = results.length;
        }

        setResultText();
        focusResult();
    }
}

function setResultText() {
    $("#resultCounter").html(currentResultIndex + " of " + results.length); // a counter of results
}

function clearSearch() { // clear the search bars text
    $("#searchBar").val("");
    search();
    $("#resultCounter").html("&nbsp;");
}

function focusResult() { // scroll to the current result and mark it
    var targetElement = results[currentResultIndex - 1];
    var offsetHeight = $(window).height() / 2;
    $("mark").removeClass("hasFocus");
    $(targetElement).addClass("hasFocus");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: ($(targetElement).offset().top - offsetHeight)
    }, 300);
}
```

```css
#loremIpsum{
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.resultBtn{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: -90px;
}

#resultCounter{
    text-align: center;
}

.hasFocus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainContent">
            <input id="searchBar" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button onclick="goToNextResult()">Next</button>
            <button onclick="goToPreviousResult()">Previous</button>
            <button onclick="clearSearch()">Clear</button>
            <p id="resultCounter">&nbsp;</p>

            <p id="loremIpsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes this is awesome. Is there a way to keep the search bar on screen, when scrolling down?

Comment: Yes sure, but you have to separate in a different element and use `position:fixed;` for example. And then I would have a look at the CSS property `overflow`